# decouple function and class into separate files

Tags: python

I have a file that has a thousand line of codes and I'd like to break it into several files. However, I found those functions depends on each other so I have no idea how to decouple those... Here is a simplified example:

```
import numpy as np

def tensor(data):
    return Tensor(data)

class Tensor:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Tensor({str(self.data)})'
    def mean(self):
        return mean(self.data)

def mean(data):
    value=np.mean(data)
    return tensor(value)
```

What is the best way to separate `tensor`, `Tensor`, and `mean` (put them into 3 different files)? Thanks for your help!!

Comment: These three objects belong to the same module. You can probably get rid of the `tensor` function, and create a `Tensor` by calling the class directly. The `mean` function does not add much either; you can replace it with the `mean` method that could directly return a `Tensor` object. You may need to first deprecate them before removing these functions though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a module that is thousands of lines long isn't that bad. You may not actually need to break it up into different modules. It is common to have a module that has a function alongside a class like your `tensor` and `Tensor` in the same module, and there is no reason for `mean` to be split up into a separate function as that code can just be placed directly in `Tensor.mean`.

A module should have a specific purpose and be a self contained unit around that purpose. If you are splitting things up just to have smaller files, then that is only going to make your codebase worse. However, large modules are a sign that things may need to be refactored. If you can find good ways of refactoring ideas in the code into smaller ideas, then those smaller units could be given their own modules, otherwise, keep everything as a bigger module.

As for how you can split up code that is coupled together. Here is one of way of splitting up the code into the modules you indicated. Since you have a function, the `tensor` function, that you would like people to use to get an instance of your `Tensor` class, it seemed like creating a Python package would be somewhat sensible since packages come with an [`__init__.py`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448271/what-is-init-py-for) file that is used for establishing the API ie your tensor function. I put the `tensor` function directly in the `__init__.py` file, but if the function is pretty large, it can be broken out into a separate module, since the `__init__.py` file is just suppose to give you an overview of the API being created.

```
# --- main.py ----

from tensor import tensor

print(tensor([1,2,3]).mean())
```

```
# --- tensor/__init__.py ----

'''
Add some documentation here
'''

def tensor(data):
    return Tensor(data)

from tensor.Tensor import Tensor
```

```
# --- tensor/Tensor.py ----

from tensor import helper

class Tensor:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
    def __repr__(self):
        return f'Tensor({str(self.data)})'
    def mean(self):
        return helper.mean(self.data)
```

```
# --- tensor/helper.py ----

import numpy as np
from . import tensor

def mean(data):
    value=np.mean(data)
    return tensor(value)
```

#### About circular dependencies

`Tensor` and `helper` are importing each other, and this is ok. When the `helper` module imports `Tensor`, and `Tensor` in turn imports `helper` again, `helper` will just continue loading normally, and then when it is done `Tensor` will finish loading. Now if you had stuff on the module level (code outside of your function/classes) being executed when the module is first loaded, and it is dependent on functionality in another module that is only partially loaded, then that is when you run into problems with circular dependencies.

#### Using classes that don't exist yet

I can add to the `__init__` file

```
def some_function(): 
    return DoesntExist()
```

and your code would still run. It doesn't look for a class named `Tensor` until it is actually running the `tensor` function. If we did the following then we would get an error about `Tensor` not existing.

```
def tensor(data):
    return Tensor(data)
tensor()
from tensor.Tensor import Tensor
```

because now we are running the tensor function before the import and it can't find anything named `Tensor`.

#### The order of stuff in __init__

If you switch the order around you will have

> `__init__` imports `Tensor` imports `helper` imports `__init__` again

as it tries to grab the `tensor` function, but it can't as the `__init__` function can't proceed past the the line that imports `Tensor` until that import has been completed.

Now with the current order we have,

> `__init__` defines `tensor`, sees the import statement, and saves its current progress as a partial import
> The same imports happen (`__init__` imports `Tensor` imports `helper` imports `__init__` looking for a `tensor` function)
> This time we look at the partial import for the tensor function, find it, and we are able to continue on using that.

I didn't think about any of that when I put things in that order. I just wrote out the code, got the circular import error, switched the order around, and didn't think about what was going on until you asked about it.

And now that I think about it, the following would have worked too.

The order of things in the __init__ file will no longer matter.

```
from tensor.Tensor import Tensor

def tensor(data):
    return Tensor(data)
```

And then in `helper.py`

```
import numpy as np
import tensor

def mean(data):
    value=np.mean(data)
    return tensor.tensor(value)
```

The difference is that now instead of specifically asking that the tensor function exist when the module is imported by trying to do `from . import tensor`, we are doing `import tensor` (which is importing the tensor package and not the function). And now, whenever the the mean function gets run, we are going to do `tensor.tensor(value)` to get the tensor function inside our tensor package.

Comment: Thanks Russell that works! I have one question, it's a bit curious that in `__init__` you defined `tensor` first (which uses `Tensor` as in `return Tensor(data)`), before actually importing `Tensor`, how does this work? I then put `from tensor.Tensor import Tensor` before `def tensor(data):` but then it shows circular import error.

Comment: I've added a couple of sections to the end of my answer to explain this.